# How to solve ctypes "while running" frozen

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes

I always use ctypes to call C++ function in Python. Currently I have designed a UI with PyQt5 to control a hardware, and call functions in dll files to control the device.
However, every time I run the function in C, python interface will just be frozen. But what I want is to run the C++ function in dll file, while I could output some information Python user interface. (Like a printing process, when I run the printing in dll file, I need to know how far the nozzle is going now).
I wonder if there is any solution to this problem.